# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise RC Licence valid for RTM?

Tags: visual-studio, licensing

Still testing some features of the Enterprise version RC. My account/license says: 60 Days left.
Can I update to RTM (either inplace or with uninstall is not the question here) and use it 60 days until I switch over to community edition or by a license?

Are there any ongoing testing licenses for updates like introduced for the Win10 preview path?

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the-inplace update. Worked fine, but I had to uninstall a 2nd RC language pack after setup and reinstall the RTM version. No problem.

**RC Licence seems to be replaced by a 90 day RTM test licence**, which is perfectly fair for me.